# Can google scan "include" php files?

Tags: php, search

I want do develop a web-page with php. I know the basics of php and built a few "intranet" php sites. Now i want do do a "online" site. Its basically a database for special electronic products.

Now i wonder about this:

```
switch ($go) {
case: something:
include (somecontent.php);
break;
}
```

my links would look like

```
thedomain.com/index.php?go=datasheet1
thedomain.com/index.php?go=datasheet2
```

Have search-engines like google the ability to scan those pages? Or only hmtl/static sites?

Answer (score 0):

Yes google can scan those files since the result will be outputed as an html page. Google crawlers (or robots) scann the page given by the servers, the php code is already executed and processed into html, Google won't have access to your php code.

Comment: So google is basically like a "human user" who clicks on links?

Comment: Not so sure for the human part but basically yeah, they explore the Internet and index files as they are rendered.